# How to detect when AVAudioPlayer ends playing?

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

By trying editing the below code, I wanted to detect when AVAudioPlayer ends playing, but it didn't work out for me. Is there any other way to detect it? I'd avoid using `AVQueuePlayer` because I have too many files and it seems like because of that, it takes a lot of time to read all the files.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(onVideoComplete),
  name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
  object: nil)
```